# Ways to deAsync.js on browser (frontend)? browserify

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, frontend, browserify, node-deasync

So, I implemented this node.js module which uses deasync.js (as I needed some synchronous computations, and javascript promise was not good enough)

Now, I had to import that to frontend side, and call it from the browser.

But, it seems like browserify.js cannot make it happen. (I see errors complaining about deasync.js part , and it does not work)

Is there any ways to make this happen? Probably frontend version of deasync.js?

I looked at npm module that does the similar job, (synchronous.js), but it seems like browserify.js doesn't like it too. (Since it depends on node(?))

Thanks.

Comment: Please tell us about your actual problem. You'll about never absolutely need a synchronous computation, especially on the server side where you can control everything.

Comment: Oh, yes. It was more of a U/X problem rather than a functionality. I could easily do the same thing with JS promises. If you think about how promise looks like, it's quite ugly compared to other languages. For, e.g. if you have var a = computeVal(user);  it's much better if you could do    console.log(a);  instead of  a.then(a=>console.log(a)).

Comment: So, deAsync.js is not possible in the front end? I assume that's because it depends on Node. Then, my question is, what makes browserify to not support Node?  other than the size  issue.

Comment: `deasync` works on node because you can hack that. You can't hack a browser.

Comment: You really should use promises then (and improve ux using concurrency). If you want nicer syntax, use `async`/`await`.

Comment: I see. Thanks @Bergi

Comment: Here's an interesting related article: [What color is your function?](http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/) While `async` / `await` provides a nice syntactic abstraction, it doesn't necessarily solve the underlying problem described in this question.